# How to count size of groups using xarray?

Tags: python, pandas, python-xarray

I'd like to count the size of groups after grouping using `groupby()`, i.e. the number of occurrences of some value. Using pandas this can be done using [`GroupBy.size()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame({'my_column': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3]}).groupby(by='my_column').size()                                                  
my_column
1    3
2    2
3    1
dtype: int64
```

Numpy supports something similar using `np.unique()`:

```
>>> np.unique([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], return_counts=True)[1]                                                                            
array([3, 2, 1])
```

Using xarray I can find only very awkward ways to achieve the same, e.g. converting the DataArray object to a Pandas DataFrame:

```
>>> d = xr.DataArray([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], name='my_column')
>>> d.to_dataframe().groupby(by='my_column').size()                                                                         
my_column
1    3
2    2
3    1
dtype: int64
```

...or do very unreadable things like:

```
>>> xr.ones_like(d).groupby(d).sum(dim='dim_0')                                                                                    
<xarray.DataArray 'my_column' (my_column: 3)>
array([3, 2, 1])
Coordinates:
  * my_column  (my_column) int64 1 2 3
```

Is there a better way to get a reduced `DataArray` object with correct coordinates and dimensions? Is there reason for not introducing a `DataArrayGroupBy.size()` method similar to Pandas?

(I was using xarray version 0.15.0 when writing this question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is to use [`GroupBy.count()`](https://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.core.groupby.DataArrayGroupBy.html):

```
>>> d = xr.DataArray([1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3], name='my_column')                                                                          
>>> d.groupby(d).count()                                                                                                            
<xarray.DataArray 'my_column' (my_column: 3)>
array([3, 2, 1])
Coordinates:
  * my_column  (my_column) int64 1 2 3
```

Comment: Oh thanks, that was easy. I've used count before, but somehow was confused by its behavior when using it with xarray Datasets. Can't see how I missed that.