# Counting occurences of each value with Xarray

Tags: statistics, tiff, python-xarray

I'm new to Xarray and trying to use it to perform analysis on heavy `tif` files (do not fit in memory, had to chunk them).
I want to get the number of pixels of each category in my dataset (single-band raster, with around 20 categories). The goal is to compute the values' distribution over the selected area.
I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64222254/how-to-count-size-of-groups-using-xarray) but it crashes because of memory usage.

How can I proceed?

Comment: Hi @peppie, could you give a bit more information on what you're trying to do? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page may help structure your question better. What would be most helpful in this case would be: (1) a printout of what you've tried before that also shows the data structure and (2) possibly a sample mockup output of what you want your result to look like

Comment: Check out [xhistogram](https://xhistogram.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) - it's designed for exactly this problem and works seamlessly with dask to compute frequency statistics on out-of-core datasets.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado this looks perfect for my case! thanks a lot for sharing, do you mind posting it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: sure! glad it helped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [`xhistogram`](https://xhistogram.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) package does exactly this. it's new and under active development, but it's designed to work with xarray and chunked dask arrays out of the box.

As an example, let's say I have a 3-D array with dims `(x, y, time)`:

```py
In [1]: import xarray as xr, numpy as np, pandas as pd
   ...:
   ...: x = np.linspace(-110, -90, 5)
   ...: y = np.linspace(23, 30, 5)
   ...: time = pd.date_range('1990-01-01', '2100-12-01', freq='MS')
   ...:
   ...: da = xr.DataArray(
   ...:     np.random.random(size=(5, 5, len(time))),
   ...:     dims=['x', 'y', 'time'],
   ...:     coords=[x, y, time],
   ...:     name='temperature',
   ...: )
```

xhistogram.xarray.histogram takes a `xr.DataArray` as an argument along with a bin spec along any number of dimensions, preserving the remaining dimensions and efficiently computing bin frequencies along the provided dim(s):

```py
In [2]: from xhistogram.xarray import histogram

In [3]: binned = histogram(da, dim=['x', 'y'], bins=[np.linspace(0, 1, 5)])

In [4]: binned
Out[4]:
<xarray.DataArray 'histogram_temperature' (time: 1332, temperature_bin: 4)>
array([[ 7,  4,  7,  7],
       [ 4,  5,  6, 10],
       [ 6,  7,  6,  6],
       ...,
       [ 8,  9,  6,  2],
       [10,  5,  5,  5],
       [ 6,  5,  5,  9]])
Coordinates:
  * time             (time) datetime64[ns] 1990-01-01 1990-02-01 ... 2100-12-01
  * temperature_bin  (temperature_bin) float64 0.125 0.375 0.625 0.875
```

It can even compute joint densities between multiple input arrays. See the [xhistogram tutorial](https://xhistogram.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) for more info.